# Store the elements of an object using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, session-storage

```
    data() {
        return: {
          user: {},
          userName: "",
          userAge: ""
    }
  },

methods: {

    saveUserName: function() {
          this.userName = this.newUserName;
          this.$refs.userNameModal.hideModal();
          this.$session.set('userDetails', {userName: this.userName});
        },

    saveUserAge: function() {
          this.userAge = this.newUserAge;
          this.$refs.userAgeModal.hideModal();
          this.$session.set('userDetails', {userAge: this.userAge});
        },

    },

    beforeMount: function() {
    if (this.$session.exists('userDetails')) {

          this.user = this.$session.get('userDetails');
          console.log("userDetails", this.user)
        }

    }
```

I have a user form, which for every entry, a Modal pops up, and the user is 
 required to fill in, and by pressing a done button, the modal closes, calls a specific function(i.e saveUserName()), which the modal, and set it to session storage.
So I am wondering how could I populate the user object time by time, and setting these values into my session storage??
As at the moment, the first value gets reset, and the second one takes over, and in my case, my user object has either userName or userAge.
What I am expecting instead (in the case that my session storage is not empty) from the log beforeMount is user: {userName: "Mario", userAge:27}
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
data() {
  return {
    user: {
      userName: "",
      userAge: ""
    },
  };
},

methods: {
  saveUserName: function() {
    this.user.userName = this.newUserName;
    this.$refs.userNameModal.hideModal();
    this.saveUser();
  },

  saveUserAge: function() {
    this.user.userAge = this.newUserAge;
    this.$refs.userAgeModal.hideModal();
    this.saveUser();
  },

  saveUser: function() {
    this.$session.set('userDetails', this.user);
  },
},

beforeMount: function() {
  if (this.$session.exists('userDetails')) {
    this.user = this.$session.get('userDetails');
    console.log("userDetails", this.user)
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was an accident. The issue here is that as soon as the user edits one of these element, the whole object gets reset back again

Comment: is this really problem? o_O 
If yes - you can create serialize/deserialize methods and store 'username' and 'userage' apart.

Comment: and you should not forget that session storage is able to store only STRINGS (not objects). So you are unable to modify a part of this string in easy-way.